# User selects an item and it searches through an array to find and count all the occurrences of the items that were selected

Tags: c#

I have been having issues with this task. I'm new to c# and I have been on this problem all day! So i give i need help. I want to create a menu that the user can select that and when  they select that selection it output the number of items and the name of them using loops and an array. This is what I have and im stuck on it. thank you in advance.

`          //Declare an array

```
        string[] arrayCart = { "Apple", "Orange", "Grape", "Orange", "Corn", "Apple", "Grape", "Apple", "Orange", "Orange" };


        Console.WriteLine("\r\nChoose and item:");
        Console.WriteLine("\r\n[1] - Apples");
        Console.WriteLine("\r\n[2] - Oranges");
        Console.WriteLine("\r\n[3] - Grape");
        Console.WriteLine("\r\n[4] - Corn");

        int cartItem = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        for (int i = 0; i < arrayCart.Length; i++)


        {

            if (cartItem == 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("In the shopping cart there are{0} {1} ", X,Y);
                break;
            }
```

//x=number of items
//y= name of the item
`

Comment: Homework? Here's a tip, you also need to store a mapping of number to item - so {1, Apple}, {2, Oranges}, etc., so you can know what to search the array for. You could even use that to drive the menu display.

Comment: yes its a homework assignment. is the only way to do it? can it be done using a 2D array or just with loops? i searched online and maybe im not searching the correct terms. your saying using the map.add method and we havent went over that yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing things is

```
        string[] arrayCart = { "Apple", "Orange", "Grape", "Orange", "Corn", "Apple", "Grape", "Apple", "Orange", "Orange" };
        Dictionary<int, string> options = new Dictionary<int, string>
        {
            [1] = "Apple",
            [2] = "Orange",
            [3] = "Grape",
            [4] = "Corn",
        };

        Console.WriteLine("\r\nChoose and item:");

        foreach (var option in options)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"\r\n[{option.Key}] - {option.Value}");
        }

        int cartItem = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        if (options.TryGetValue(cartItem, out var insertedOption))
        {
            var count = arrayCart.Count(x => string.Equals(x, insertedOption));
            Console.WriteLine($"In the shopping cart there are {count} {insertedOption}");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Given option doesn't exist");
        }
```

You should store a mapping between the number the user enters and the distinct option you have in the list.

Then since you stored that map, you could loop on it, and ask the user to enter an option.

You then read the input, and get the mapping option from the dictionary.

You then use Linq to Count the number of strings that match the mapped input.

If you don't want to use Linq then you could do

```
        if (options.TryGetValue(cartItem, out var insertedOption))
        {
            int count = 0;
            foreach (var item in arrayCart)
            {
                if (string.Equals(item, insertedOption))
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"In the shopping cart there are {count} {insertedOption}");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Given option doesn't exist");
        }
```

Comment: Thank you guy btw.

Comment: You could try to let students think for themselves just a little.

Comment: @Crowcoder I understand what you are saying, I was not looking for an up vote, in the question he said he was stuck, I do understand what you are saying and I agree with it.

Comment: I been on it for 2 days and cant figure it out. i would to spend more time but the work is piling up. i was doin fine until i got to this problem.

Comment: @Rockit we were all students someday, I understand how one could get stuck on a problem even small ones.

Comment: Ill take another stab it this afternoon its 5:18am in vegas n havent slept. ima take a nap bc the brain cant even think right now thank you

Comment: heres another ignorant question how do i like ur guys or "reputations" im new here as well my first day in combat lol - nvd found it. i know i have a long way relax! i just ask for patience.

Comment: Yeah you should really get into all your homework work or just work really with a fresh mind. No sleep is no good for problem solving. For reputation you just click the up arrow next to answer/comment. If the answer is acceptable to you, you click the check mark next to the answer. Anyway you don't really have to up vote or accept the answer. No one is looking.